# Javascript in browser, print data to file

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser

Im running a javascript trading application in my browser, provided by my bank. The application gives me realtime data on stock quotes etc. Is there anyway i can get the browser to make the data available outside the browser, like writing the info to a file every ten seconds? Im using firefox.

Comment: As Trufa suggested I think the only way the do this is a plugin. Those usually have priviliged access.

Comment: So, i guess you do not know of any extensions that does this?

Comment: Using server side code you can have AJAX that cause file to be created on the server every 10 seconds then user can be prompted to download this file.

Answer (score 1):

No, the Javascript is running in a sandbox. You can write it into a html5 database build in with your browser.

May be, the application is using a SOAP-Service, which you can use directly.

Comment: Any references for how to implement such a html5 database?

Comment: http://blog.darkcrimson.com/2010/05/local-databases/ But you still have to inject Javascript. And I am unsure, if another programm can access this database(file) if your browser is opened.

Answer (score 0):

there is a way save the web pages. hope it will help you.
The add on is available to save web pages in mozilla.
see https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/auto-save-document/

Comment: Just tried it. Its exactly the type of addon im looking for except it only writes a bunch of html/javascript (actually seems to be some kind of internal javascript-code) to the file, not any values or anything from the actual webpage.

Answer (score 0):

There is a straight-forward approach, that requires a server (even if it's a very dumb one):  You could post the data to the server and have it respond with a file containing the posted data (no more, no less) that the user is prompted to save.

Comment: Its a trading application. I have to log in through the browser using a physical code generator, my birth-ID and a self-chosen password. I guess its not that straightforward. At least not for me.